# Alter color of table rows per which resets every sub-heading

Tags: html, css

Altering colors for rows of table in `css` can be achieved with `tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}`. But I have some different kind of data.

```
|a |b |c |d | ---style class 1
|     h1    | ---style class 2
|a1|b1|c1|d1| ---style class 3
|     h2    | ---style class 2
|a2|b2|c2|d2| ---style class 3
|a3|b3|c3|d3| ---style class 4
```

where `h1, h2` are subheadings spanning the all columns. `a,b,c,d` are table headers. I want to alter row color and the pattern resets per subheading . Headings have different styling. Also table header has its own styling.

How this can  be achieved gracefully.

EDIT:
The content under sub-headings(`h1, h2`) is generated dynamically.

Comment: can you show your html please?

Comment: add class to headings (`<td class="heading">...h1...</td>`). And set background in CSS (`.heading {background-color: #CCC}`). Or if there is same number of rows between headings, use `nth-child(Xn+0)` (replace X with a number)

Comment: Put the headings in with a `th` tag, then style that. That's what it is for.

Comment: Did you mean `<h1> <h2>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can not target parent element. This can be done by jquery

```
$('h1').parent().css('background', 'red');

$('h2').parent().css('background', 'green');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IWomazo/2/)**

Comment: Purely academic, but CSS 4 provides functionality for this using `!td > h1` (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject). This of course is not yet implemented!

Comment: I am using this in a an email(motley used in outlook) so don't want to use jquery(I even do not know if it is supported).

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam R u sure that u using nth-child for email template?

Comment: @Sowmya yes I checked it in outlook and it worked. I put the style element in head and used classes.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam if it's an email, what's wrong with using inline styles?

Comment: @BenM It gets messy that's all. Too much of writing. This would be a easier way so was curious if can be done with pure css.

Comment: Most mail clients still prefer inline CSS as far as I can tell. It might be messy, but it's still a better solution for styling HTML emails. The answer to your question is that it cannot be achieved using pure CSS, **yet**. The specification for CSS Level 4 selectors does include a method for this, but it's not implemented in any web browser yet, let alone email client. Using this, you could do `!td > h1`, but not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in CSS alone

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Py6cr/1/)

Assuming your subheader rows have `colspan` set, you can simply target those cell elements with the applicable property, via (e.g.)

```
table td[colspan='4']{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use numbers like `4` because the content is dynamically generated.

Comment: Assuming your main header elements are `th` and your subheaders are `td` with colspan set, just use table `td[colspan]` - you dont need to set the `4` or any other number, this will then isolate any `td` with colspan, specifically your subheaders..